# If the sensorites can read minds, why do they not trust The Doctor and his companions?

Tags: doctor-who

In the season one episode of Doctor Who classic, the Sensorites, a species who can read minds (at least of Susan) still suspect that the humans may not be trustworthy.

Surely, if they can know what Susan is thinking and feeling (such as being able to ‘hear her distress‘ when she asks how long Ian has got left to live), then they should have no worries about being betrayed?

Comment: https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0330.html is relevant.  Nobody would trust the Doctor after reading his mind even superficially.